# Time Machine stopped worked with "failed to unmount file"

Tags: backup, time-machine, nas

I use a Synology NAS to backup my family's MacBooks. Two are still working fine, but one of them was unable to make a backup for about a week. Because the other two MacBooks are still fine I am pretty sure that the issue is not related to the recent MacOS update nor to the recent Synology firmware update.

The log file has repeating sections like the following:

```
2021-11-05 10:29:52: TMPowerState: 2
2021-11-05 10:30:22: TMPowerState: 2
2021-11-05 10:30:22: Not prioritizing backups with priority errors. lockState=0
2021-11-05 10:30:22: Starting automatic backup
2021-11-05 10:30:22: Attempting to mount 'smb://[USERNAME]@Synology._smb._tcp.local./time-machine'
2021-11-05 10:30:26: Mounted 'smb://[USERNAME]@Synology._smb._tcp.local./time-machine' at '/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine' (111,02 GB of 805,31 GB available)
2021-11-05 10:30:26: Initial network volume parameters for 'time-machine' {disablePrimaryReconnect: 0, disableSecondaryReconnect: 0, reconnectTimeOut: 60, QoS: 0x0, attributes: 0x1C}
2021-11-05 10:30:26: Configured network volume parameters for 'time-machine' {disablePrimaryReconnect: 0, disableSecondaryReconnect: 0, reconnectTimeOut: 30, QoS: 0x20, attributes: 0x1C}
2021-11-05 10:31:03: Failed to delete 'file:///Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine/DCC98B45-7855-4FAA-B130-5FC56A017ED3.purgeable.sparsebundle/', error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“DCC98B45-7855-4FAA-B130-5FC56A017ED3.purgeable.sparsebundle” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
Remove :     Remove
), NSFilePa: "No such file or directory"}}
2021-11-05 10:31:03: Invalid mountpoint '/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine' - no volume mounted at this path
2021-11-05 10:31:03: Failed to unmount '/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine', Disk Management error: {
Action =:     Action = Unmount;
Target =:     Target = "file:///Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine/";
} : }
2021-11-05 10:31:03: Failed to unmount '/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine', error: Error Domain=com.apple.diskmanagement Code=0 "No error" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No error, NSLocalizedDescription=Kein Fehler.}
2021-11-05 10:31:03: Waiting 60 seconds and trying again.
2021-11-05 10:31:03: Cancelling backup because volume '/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine' was unmounted.
2021-11-05 10:31:03: Requested backup cancellation or termination
2021-11-05 10:31:04: Backup cancelled (22: BACKUP_CANCELED)
2021-11-05 10:31:04: Failed to unmount '/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine', Disk Management error: {
Action =:     Action = Unmount;
Target =:     Target = "file:///Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine/";
} : }
2021-11-05 10:31:04: Failed to unmount '/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine', error: Error Domain=com.apple.diskmanagement Code=0 "No error" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No error, NSLocalizedDescription=Kein Fehler.}
2021-11-05 10:31:04: Cleared pending cancellation request
```

Interesting detail: The folder that failed to unmount (`/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66/time-machine` in this example) is always different on each try. And it is always created at the time the backup attempt started. And it always contains only one empty folder called `time-machine`:

`drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B  5 Nov 10:30 3C582361-50A6-47F2-947C-86A99A2B1A66`

What I tried so far:

- Run hard disk tests on the Synology NAS (all HDDs are fine)
- Disabled and enabled Time Machine
- Run Disk Utility – First Aid on all disks
- Manually deleted all existing folders in `/Volumes/.timemachine/Synology._smb._tcp.local./`
- Told Time Machine to remove the existing backup and start from scratch
- Rebooted the Mac a couple of times

None of that made a difference. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: I've been having the same error lately, oddly enough, after the latest security update of MacOS Catalina. I wonder if there was some security fix (hence affecting both Catalina and the latest version, at around the same time). It's an odd error message, "No Error", implying it actually is working, but misinterpreting itself as if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue but telling macOS to back up to an external USB drive instead of to the Synology NAS via Wi-Fi.

After that backup to the USB drive was successful, I switched back to the Synology NAS and macOS was able to back up without any issues.